# mysql select combining more conditions

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I have 2 tables with values like below:

```
**tbl_users**
user_ID      name     
1          somename1   
2          somename2   
3          somename3   

**tbl_interviews**
int_ID     user_ID      answer          date      
 1            1         sometextaba   2012-11-04 
 2            2         sometextxcec  2012-10-05
 3            1         sometextabs   2011-06-04
 4            3         sometextxcfc  2012-11-04
 5            3         sometextxcdn  2012-11-04
```

Now.. I should count the people that has been interviewd this year AND in the years before.
unfortunately I'm not able even to select them.. I'm trying something like this.. but it's not working (not throwing a syntax error but giving an empty result):

```
SELECT * FROM interviews WHERE ('YEAR(date) = 2012' AND 'YEAR(date) < 2012')
```

Comment: sorry.. i suppose i placed a bad question... what i mean is something like this: how can i ask mysql tell me who is the only user in the table above that was interviewed this year but had another interview in the previous years? the only one is the user with id = 1 (since he had an interview (the int_id 1) this year, but the first interview was in 2011 (int-id 3). )

Answer (score 1):

You can't match *both* conditions. You mean *either* condition

```
SELECT * FROM interviews WHERE ('YEAR(date) = 2012' OR 'YEAR(date) < 2012');
```

Better though, makes it SARGable

```
SELECT * FROM interviews WHERE date < '2013-01-01');

SELECT * FROM interviews WHERE date < CONCAT('''', YEAR(CURDATE()), '-01-01''');
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
SELECT * FROM interviews WHERE YEAR(date) <= YEAR(GETDATE())
```

GETDATE() basically gives you the current date.

Now if your looking into counting how many people were interviewed it would be something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) FROM interviews WHERE YEAR(date) <= YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from tbl_interviews where year(date)<='2012'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should simply be:

```
SELECT     COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) 
FROM       tbl_interviews
```

Explanation: your question is: "I should count the people that has been interviewd this year AND in the years before."

First of, this part: "this year AND in the years before" means people interviewed this year, as well as every year before this year. Since you can't have any interviews that occur in the future, this essentially means all interviews regardless of the year.

If that's not what you meant, then please rephrase your question. (I have an idea, see below)

As for "I should count the people", I take that to mean you want to count each individual that was interviewd, regardless of how many interviews they did. This is done by simply counting unique user_id's, which is done with COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id))

Now, regarding your "this year AND in the years before", maybe you meant:

"I want to see the number of users we interviewed this year, and the number of users we interviewed in the years prior to this year" then the query would be:

```
SELECT     (
           SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
           FROM   tbl_interviews
           WHERE  date >= CONCAT(YEAR(current_date()), '-01-01')
           ) thisyear
,          (
           SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
           FROM   tbl_interviews
           WHERE  date < CONCAT(YEAR(current_date()), '-01-01')
           ) previousyears
```